# Wordpress ajax works on FF but not on IE & chrome

Tags: ajax, browser-compatibility

I have the following code

```
<a href="#" class="loadmore centered" page-data="1">Show More</a><script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            $(".loadmore").on("click", function() {
                offset = $(".loadmore").attr("page-data");
                $(this).text("'.__("Loading..", "pe").'");
                $.post(
                    "'.admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ).'", 
                    {
                        "action": "load_posts",
                        "offset": offset,
                    }, 
                    function(response){
                        $("#posts-container").append(response);
                        $(".loadmore").text("'. __("Show More", "pe").'");
                        $(".loadmore").attr("page-data", parseInt(offset)+1);
                        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(".loadmore").position().top}, "slow");
                    }
                );
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and the following PHP code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts', 'pe_ajax_load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts', 'pe_ajax_load_posts');
function pe_ajax_load_posts() {
    $offset = $_POST['offset'];
    $html = pe_load_posts(intval($offset)+1);
    echo $html;
    die();
}
function pe_load_posts($page)  {
    $news = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged'=>$page));
    if ($news->have_posts()): 
        $html .="<div class='clearfix'>";
        while($news->have_posts()): $news->the_post();
            $html .='<div class="post"> <div class="img">'.get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(), 'fp-thumb' ).'</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="post-content"><h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
            $html .='<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>';
            $html .= '<p><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="more">'.__('Read More', 'pe').'</a></p></div></div>';
        endwhile; 
        $html .= "</div>";
    endif;
    return $html;
}
```

The code works fine on FF and I get an extra 2 posts blocks
on IE & chrome however it does not.
I get an empty response

any idea?

this is the link: http://test.hannitcohen.co.il/pe/?lang=en

Comment: Was this ever solved on your side?